# Magento2 customer dashboard

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-account, account-dashboard

How can I show last order view on my customer panel dashboard?
by default it shows last orders... I want to show last order view(detail) on dashboard.
finally i tried this code

```
foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
     echo $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName());
}
```

but have a problem, when i have 3 items in one order id it shows like item1 item2 item3. i want to show item1 item2 item3... with image of product. any help?

Now used this code but still cant see all product images, just shows one of them...

```
<?php foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
                        echo "Order date: " . $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt());
                        $_imagehelper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
                        if($childProd = current($_item->getChildrenItems())){
                            $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($childProd->getProduct(), 'category_page_list', array('height' => 156 , 'width'=> 170))->getUrl();
                        }
                        else{
                            $productImage = $_imagehelper->init($_item->getProduct(), 'category_page_list', array('height' => 156 , 'width'=> 170))->getUrl();
                        }

                    }
                    ?>
```

Comment: share your phtml file code where you want to display product image.

Answer (score 0):

**In your block file Add below code :**

```
public function getOrderItems()
{        
    $order_items = [];
    foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
            $order_items[] = $_item;
    }
    return $order_items;
}
```

**In your phtml file add below code :**

```
$productCollection = $block->getOrderItems();
$viewMode = 'list';
$_imageHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');

if (count($productCollection)){ ?>

<div class="page-title-wrapper" id="trending-product-list">
    <h2 class="page-title">
        <span class="base" data-ui-id="page-title-wrapper"><?php echo __('Welcome to Feedback page'); ?></span>
    </h2>
</div>
<div class="custom-review products-wrapper <?php echo $viewMode; ?> products-<?php echo $viewMode; ?>">
    <ol class="products list items product-items">
        <?php foreach ($productCollection as $product): ?>
        <?php if(in_array($product->getProductType(), $block->getProductTypes())){ ?>
        <li class="item product product-item" style="padding-bottom: 45px;">
            <div class="product-item-info" data-container="product-grid">                
                <a href="" class="product photo product-item-photo" tabindex="-1">
                    <span class="product-image-container" style="width:240px;">
                        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 125%;">
                            <img class="product-image-wrapper" src="<?= $_imageHelper->init($product->getProduct(), 'small_image', ['type'=>'small_image'])->keepAspectRatio(true)->resize('240','300')->getUrl();?>" alt="<?= __('Product Image');?>">
                        </span>
                    </span>                    
                </a>
                <div class="product details product-item-details">
                    <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link"
                           href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo$block->getProductUrl($product->getProductId()); ?>">
                               <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $product->getName(); ?>
                        </a>
                    </strong>                       
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
            <?php } endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
</div>
<?php }else{ echo 'No product item found'; } ?>
```

**Note :** Do note use objectmanager.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but it just shows image of one item not all items... i want to show each product image in one order

Comment: You have to put this code in foreach loop phtml

Comment: Could you please give me code? i used into                             <?php foreach ($_order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
but it goes to blank page with no code

Comment: share your block & phtml file code so I can help you similarly. Don't worry you can share your code in your question.

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I have updated my answer see

Comment: Undefined variable: _order when i added on block get this